Are there Sudoku variants which are useful or mathematically deep?
I was recently watching a Sudoku Youtube channel which shows a large number of variants on the traditional Sudoku puzzle, some of them non-trivial to solve.  I think there was some mention of a Sudoku puzzle which uses Euler's identity, although can't remember the details.  Some of them use prime numbers or certain sequences like the Fibonacci sequence, and so on.
I was wondering if there could be anything more mathematically profound or useful in variants of these puzzles apart from the combinatorial search for a solution.
Something like this seems to be a recent paper of Greenfeld and Tao on undecidability of translational monotilings which uses Sudoku puzzles extensively (or at least, a so-called "Sudoku puzzle construction").  A variant of a Sudoku problem was used to encode a domino problem which can be viewed as a generalisation of the "Wang tiling problem".  The Sudoku puzzle construction was also used in a related paper to produce an aperiodic translational monotiling.

Here is a recent math paper about Sudoku: https://doi.org/10.5802/alco.375

The name of @SamHopkins's reference: Dukes and Nimegeers - The linear system for Sudoku and a fractional completion threshold.

In error correction there is such a thing as a Sudoku Code, but I think they're more of a curiosity than a useful tool.
